# which Arduino UNO ethernet shield supports power over ethernet?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, ethernet

I ordered for this ethernet shield for my UNO as shown on the [amazon website listing](https://www.amazon.in/gp/aw/d/B00RFGSM0M/ref=yo_ii_img?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

[image]
I was thinking to add power over ethernet module to take advantage of shield that supports adding POE module.

[image]

.

But I received the one below

[image]

[image: under side of the ethernet shield received from amazon listing linked above]

Does the one I received POE? Without the use of POE module!

Comment: No, it's not possible at all with this "MagJack". But you can always use injectors/extractors with 9V or 12V power supply...